# map the data frame using list in R

Tags: r

I have a list

```
a = c(4,3,5,1,2)
```

and a data frame

```
b= data.frame("aa"=c(1,2,3,4,5),"bb"=c(100,90,80,70,60))
```

where i need to rearrange data frame "b" in a such a way that the value of first element of "a" shows the row of data frame "b".

The output would be

```
 aa  bb
4  4 70
3  3  80
5  5  60
1  1  100
2  2  90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a simple indexation will work here :

```
> b[a,]
  aa  bb
4  4  70
3  3  80
5  5  60
1  1 100
2  2  90
```